# Robot FrameworkNo: keyword with name 'AutoItLibrary.Run' found

Tags: python, robotframework

I have the test script:

```
*** Settings ***
Library     AutoItLibrary
*** Variables ***
*** Test Cases ***
Launch HTOOL UI

    AutoItLibrary.Run  MyApp.exe  C:\\MyFolder\\AppFolder
```

Robot Framework is returning the error `No keyword with name 'AutoItLibrary.Run' found.`

When I installed the setup.pu for AutoIt I got these logs:

> C:\My Files\AutoItLibrary-1.1>python setup.py install
>   Don't think we need to unregister the old one...
>   %SYSTEMROOT%\system32\regsvr32.exe /S C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\AutoItLibrary\lib\AutoItX3.dll
>   python C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\makepy.py
>
> C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\AutoItLibrary\lib\AutoItX3.dll
>   Generating to C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\win32com\gen_py\F8937E53-D444-4E71-9275-35B64210CC3Bx0x1x0.py
>   Building definitions from type library...
>   Generating...
>   Importing module
>   running install
>   running build
>   running build_py
>   running install_lib
>   byte-compiling 
>   C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\AutoItLibrary\Logger.py to Logger.c
>   python-35.pyc
>     File "C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\AutoItLibrary\Logger.py", line 28
>       print '*%s* %s' % (level, message)
>                     ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> byte-compiling C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\AutoItLibrary__init__.py to **init**.cpython-35.pyc
>     File "C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\AutoItLibrary__init__.py", line 269
>       raise Exception, "Failed to run %s" % cmd
>                      ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> running install_data
>   running install_egg_info
>   Removing C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\AutoItLibrary-1.1-py3.5.egg-info
>   Writing C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\AutoItLibrary-1.1-py3.5.egg-info

I would like to seek for your opinion on why I am getting the error.

Comment: Please use proper formatting.

Comment: Why didn't you read the logs?

Comment: You are running python 3, but it looks like AutoIT hasn't been ported to 3 since it's  using some python 2.x syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install run as administrator.

I tried installing normal cmd i too faced same issue. when i try to install using cmd run as administrator this issue got resolved.